# Unable to detect touchdown events on actors in stage LIBGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch-event

I am making a game in libgdx.

Each Level has a class. I have added a stage to each level. Actors have also been added to this stage. I have used to detect events on the stage.

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

The level object is instantiated in another class known as GameScreen. GameScreen extends the Game class.

I am unable to detect touch events on my actors in the stage. I have added the following code on each actor to detect touch.

```
this.addListener(new InputListener(){
     public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
          System.out.println("touchdown at " + x + " " + y);
          return true;
      }
  });
```

Is there something I am missing. Is my Levels class supposed to extend another class?

Answer (score 1):

Do you set bounds while creating new actor? It's important, every actor should have bounds set, or it will not register any touches.
So, actor constructor should look something like:

```
    public someActor(){
    setBounds(someActorXPosition, someActorYPosition, someActorWidth, someActorHeight);
    this.addListener(new InputListener(){
...rest of your code...
```

And then, anytime you move your actor, dont forget to set new bounds.
Worked for me

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do the bounds coordinates have to be screen coordinates? I currently set the position to be as per world coordinates.

Comment: if you see the documentation (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#setBounds-float-float-float-float-) it says that parameters to setBound should be a float, so it must be world coordinates.

Comment: Thats not necessary. your world coordinates can be in float too. Its just that the unit of world cooridnates changes to meters and the numeric value reduces.

Comment: @Mobador - I tried with both world and screen cooridnates. Touch doesn't get recognized at all. Does your level class implement any interface or extends the InputAdapter?

Comment: @Rahul. My example worked in very simple application, without even using Game class. I created stage straight in main class, and then i put actor on this stage. My main class implements ApplicationListener.
If in your case GameScreen and Game class causes trouble, then sorry for giving totally unrelated answer...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mobador. I think since you implement the ApplicationListener, all the touch calls are being intercepted by the main class. In my case I have the Level class which has the stage in it. However, now I tried to add stage to the GameScreen class yet nothing happens. Is it possible for you to upvote the questions, may be other folks can help me out as it becomes popular due to upvoting.